# How to use biblatex to organise relevant literature for a thesis or paper most efficiently?

Tags: biblatex

I've been using LaTeX to write any kind of document for some years. Some years ago I also discovered `biblatex` which is great. In fact, I've never used `bibtex` seriously and directly jumped upon the `biblatex` waggon.

At the moment I am preparing my Masters' thesis. I am in the very early reading phase and try to collect and summarise texts for later use. Literature that I find interesting I put in one single `.bib` file which I manage with `JabRef`. I am wondering how I can do this more efficiently; so in the following I am explaining how I do it where I see problems and possible improvements.

Once I take a closer look on an article, I create an entry in the `.bib` file. Literature this article refers to or is related to I add as well. I use the `xref` field to refer the latter to the former. As you can imagine my database is growing and growing. The`.bib` file and articles (in `.pdf` format) are in the same folder. The `.pdf` files are named like the (primary) key of their entry in the database; hence, ALT-F (in `JabRef`) connects an entry with its `pdf` counter-part quite easily. Summaries of the articles I name like the articles but add "-summary" to their name, like `Author1987Analysis-summary.pdf` is the summary of `Author1987Analysis.pdf`

Now here comes the tricky part which I don't know how to solve. In the summary, I refer to what I summarise with the help of biblatex. At the end I add the bibliography. Usually it only contains one reference which is -- of course -- the article I summarise. I would like to add another bibliography which includes all the entries of my database that are related to the articles I summarise; hence, I need some piece of code that loops through the database and gives back all those articles which have "Author1987Analysis" in their `xref` field. How do I do this?

In `biblatex`' documentation I guess it is the "Authors' Guide" I need to refer to. But I am not sure where to start since I do not know how to loop through all the entries. Maybe I could also `\nocite{*}` everything and then filter through all the entries but I guess I might run into some performance issues since my database I quite big -- and this is probably not the most convenient way of doing it.

I put the question of this post quite generally since I am not sure whether there might be a better approach. My main aim is to get an overview of the bibliographic database by printing a summary of each entry and those it "`xref`ers" to. Maybe even the `reading` bibliography style of `biblatex` might solve my problem -- though I guess my abstracts can't be that sophisticated as they are right now since I would need to put everything in the `abstract` field.

I am grateful for any ideas and experiences.

Comment: My first reaction is that `xref` isn't really the correct mechanism to be using - it is designed to trigger citing of a parent item when enough of the children are cited.  If starting from scratch I would be inclined to create an `entryset` for the related items to a given article, i.e. if the article is `myart` then create an entryset `myart-rels` containing the keys of the related articles.  One reason for this is that a given item may be related to and relate to serveral others in different ways, I don't see how `xref` captures that.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, thank you for your reply. I figured out I might have complicated things by trying to implement what I needed on the database level. Since I assign related articles in any event by hand, I can also add a `refsection` and `\nocite{<related-articles>}` at the end of each summary I write. There is no filtering needed and I get the "main" references as well as the related once.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to at least consider another tool than bib files + JabRef if you plan to add notes and crosslinks for a long period. Building up such a database is a lot of work, and there are modern tools that can support you. All of them can export a bib file at any time, at the click of a button.

Wikipedia has an article on reference mangement software:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_management_software
and a quite long comparison list of tools:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software

If you prefer free/libre software, give **Zotero** a try, if you do not mind using commercial software you could also try Mendeley, EndNote, Citavi and so on.